# How do I add child elements to XML using Perl's XML::Twig?

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

I have the following XML file:

```
<SOURCE_SERVER>
  <SERVER HOSTNAME="serv1">
      <CIFS_SERVICE NETBIOSNAME="serv1"/>
  </SERVER>
  <SERVER HOSTNAME="serv2">
  </SERVER>
<SOURCE_SERVER>
```

Now, I want to add child `<CIFS_SERVICE NETBIOSNAME="serv2"/>` to `<SERVER HOSTNAME="serv2">`. How do I do this using [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XML::Twig)?

Comment: I reformatted your post so that the XML visible. Is there really no closing `</SOURCE_SERVER>` in your XML file? Did you mean you want to add `<CIFS_SERVICE NETBIOSNAME="serv2">` to `<SERVER HOSTNAME="serv1">`? Please edit your post to reflect the correct requirements.

Comment: I've made the correction Sinan

Comment: @Ninja See my answer below. Is `<CIFS_SERVICE NETBIOSNAME="serv1">` correct? Shouldn't that be `<CIFS_SERVICE NETBIOSNAME="serv1"/>`? Otherwise, it is not XML.

Comment: Yes, you are right Sinan...it's a typo..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution incorporating what I think are reasonable fixes to your question. The code below is based on the [filtering example](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XML::Twig#Building_an_XML_filter) given in the documentation.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $t = XML::Twig->new(
    twig_roots => { SERVER => \&update },
    twig_print_outside_roots => 1,
);

$t->parse(\*DATA);

sub update {
    my ($t, $server) = @_;
    if ( 'serv2' eq $server->att('HOSTNAME') ) {
        $server->insert(
            CIFS_SERVICE => { NETBIOSNAME => 'serv2' },
        );
    }
    $server->print;
}


__DATA__
<SOURCE_SERVER>
  <SERVER HOSTNAME="serv1">
      <CIFS_SERVICE NETBIOSNAME="serv1" />
  </SERVER>
  <SERVER HOSTNAME="serv2">
  </SERVER>
</SOURCE_SERVER>
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> x
<SOURCE_SERVER>
  <SERVER HOSTNAME="serv1"><CIFS_SERVICE NETBIOSNAME="serv1"/></SERVER>
  <SERVER HOSTNAME="serv2"><CIFS_SERVICE NETBIOSNAME="serv2"/></SERVER>
</SOURCE_SERVER>
```

Comment: Sinan, thanks a ton for your answer. However, I have one more query. Actually my xml looks like this: `<SOURCE_SERVER> <SERVER HOSTNAME="serv1"> <CIFS_SERVICE NETBIOSNAME="serv1"/> </SERVER> <SERVER HOSTNAME="serv2"> <CIFS_SERVICE /> </SERVER> </SOURCE_SERVER>` So, I don't need to insert <CIFS_SERVICE> tag. The twig points to SERVER and I need to set attribute of it's child. How do I do it? Please help me.