# Modifying an XML File using Perl

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

I have an XML file, with some format. I want the data to be modified in some way I want. I feel [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XML::Twig) is the way to do it.

I want to know if there is any other better alternative?

Comment: I bet for some definition of "better" there is some alternative. Yes.

Comment: Are you asking for the best XML parser for Perl? It sounds to me like you are. In that case, this question is a duplicate.

Comment: Not exactly parsing. See i know parsing dude. Actually i want to read the data, modify it as i want then write to it another XML file

Comment: OK dood .. then read the data, modify it and write the output. What part of that is giving you problems?

Comment: Swati, I see you only joined today. Just a quick tip -- suggest you look at the faq tab and the [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) site. You will get a log more cooperation if you phrase your question clearly and show at least some effort in solving it yourself!

Comment: You don't even have to have a look at the FAQ. Just picture yourself in our shoes. How would you try to answer a question as that?

Answer (score 10):

You will probably find the [`XML::Twig`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/) is an ideal tool for the task and there have been plenty of questions/answers on Stack Overflow that seem to reaffirm this:

- [In Perl, how can I change an element in an XML file without changing the format of the XML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327720/in-perl-how-can-i-change-an-element-in-an-xml-file-without-changing-the-format-o/1329189#1329189)
- [Can you provide an example of parsing HTML with your favorite parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773340/can-you-provide-an-example-of-parsing-html-with-your-favorite-parser/773496#773496)
- [How can I extract some XML data from a URL using XML::Twig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524597/how-can-i-extract-some-xml-data-from-a-url-using-xmltwig)
- [How can I add an attribute to a child element using Perl’s XML::Twig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264506/how-can-i-add-an-attribute-to-a-child-element-using-perls-xmltwig)
- [How can I get content using XML::Twig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447632/how-can-i-get-content-using-xmltwig)
- [How do I add child elements to XML using Perl’s XML::Twig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259692/how-do-i-add-child-elements-to-xml-using-perls-xmltwig)

You may also find it helpful to know that the author of XML::Twig does answer questions on this site: [Mirod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11095/mirod).

However if you really are looking for an alternative then have a look at [`XML::LibXML`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/).  This module is based on [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/) library ([XML::Twig](http://xmltwig.com/) is written on top of [`XML::Parser`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Parser/) which uses the [expat](http://www.jclark.com/xml/expat.html) library).

Mirod himself lists [alternatives to XML::Twig](http://xmltwig.com/xmltwig/XML-Twig-FAQ.html#Q7) in his [FAQ](http://xmltwig.com/xmltwig/XML-Twig-FAQ.html).